# Shuffle files while keeping filename the same

Tags: php, image

I need a script to shuffle around some images but leave the resource filename the same.

I'm using the following PHP script called from a cron job every five minutes.  It works, but is inelegant.

```
<?php

rename("/www/images/vvx300-background.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background-X.png");

sleep(5); //a precaution I guess

rename("/www/images/vvx300-background-B.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background.png");

sleep(5);

rename("/www/images/vvx300-background-C.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background-B.png");

sleep(5);

rename("/www/images/vvx300-background-X.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background-C.png");

?>
```

So, there are 3 images:
The current image is moved to X. 
(pause 5) 
B is moved to replace current image.
(pause 5) 
C is renamed to B.
(pause 5) 
X is renamed to C.

Surely this isn't the best way to do this....

If you are curious, these are IP phone screen idle images to give the user a bit of variety - the phones reach out to a fixed URL for their images, thus the need to keep the resource filename the same.  The files are on a web host and I can't do a shell script.

Your suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: One way may be to use an array with all of the image paths and then copy paste (and overwrite) the "output image"

Comment: Could you flesh out your suggestion?

Comment: I wrote the answer just now, and after writing it I saw your comment :-) I was just waiting til I got out of bed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an idea what I mean in the comment.

```
$output = "/www/images/vvx300-background.png";
$files = array("/www/images/vvx300-background-A.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background-B.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background-C.png", "/www/images/vvx300-background-D.png");

Foreach($files as $file){  // or foreach(glob("/www/images/*.png") as $file){
     Copy($file, $output);
     Sleep(5);
}
```

This way $output is the path you give to the phones, and if you add a new image you can add it in the array (or possibly use glob to find all files and skip the manual array).

Note that this will give you two copies of one file all the time. Your original and the output. Then change the output image every 5 seconds.

> EDIT I see now that your five second delay is not to swap image on the phones.
>
> This method will save a txt file with the current image used and then go to the next one.

```
$output = "/www/images/vvx300-background.png";
$files = glob("/www/images/*.png"); 
$current = file_get_contents("current.txt"); // change path to suit. reads current image index

if(!isset($current) || $current == count($files)-1) {
     Copy($files[0], $output);
}else{
     Copy($files[$current+1], $output);
}

file_put_contents("current.txt", $current+1); // saves the index of the current image used.
```

The first time you run this code it will generate an warning becuase the file current.txt does not exist.
But at the end of the code it will create the file and all will be ruinning smoth after the first run.

Edited to change method from rename to copy

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, I must be misunderstanding your suggestion.  Your code renames each file vvx300-background.png effectively deleting the other files.  What I am looking to do is cycle through each of the images in turn, changing their names to be vvx300-background.png while preserving the image files.

Comment: @Michael that is correct. My suggestion is to have one file name that is just temporary. All files that you wish to keep is called ...-A or -B and so on. The one called background only will be the one that will be on display. Because.... Wait.. now I understand my misstake. It should not be rename() it should be copy(). So basically, A, B, C and so on are original, and background is a copy that will be replaced each time you run the php file.

Comment: @Michael is my answer still not working? The idea is to keep the files ending with A, B, C and so on and replace the file called background by copy and replace.

Comment: Andreas - thanks.  I accepted your question to thank you for your efforts.  Eventually I went with a different solution - outputting the image using imagecreatefrompng - but you answered my original question about not changing the filename... thanks.  One more thing... what is it with SO these days and down voting questions?  Was this a particularly dumb question?

Comment: @Michael I wish I could answer you on that. In my opinion there is a downvote infection on php tag. Go to Excel tag and look at them there. If you make a wrong answer someone will help you and comment how to fix it. Here on php you get downvoted before you even have a chance to click on edit. It's a shame. But no. Your question was not bad. Slightly unclear but that could be me, I think it got lost in translation to my native language. But generally if it's not a "normal" question (WordPress, database etc.) then prepare to get downvoted. Unless it's crystal clear question. No, off course not.

Comment: *.. You will get downvoted for any out of the ordinary question.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I finally did but it does not comply with the original question. That is why I selected the answer above.  I used that answer's methods in addition to php's image handling functions.

This php is the image resource and not the static png file.

```
<?php

$files = glob("images/*.png");
$current = file_get_contents("current.txt");

if (count($files) <= $current) {
    $current = 1;
} else {
     $current++;
}

$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/".$current.".png");

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

file_put_contents("current.txt", $current); 

?>
```